Formula to search for "18" in row 1, place it below where it's found, and sequentially continue with numbers from 19 onwards in the second row
one excel formula for the following:

Search the Row 1 for the value = 18
In the row below place 18 in the cell directly below the cell where 18 was found in the row 1.
In row 2, once you have found 18, place 19,20,21,22,23 , 24, 25, 26 in cells after the 18 the second row

=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(18, $1:$1, 0)=COLUMN(), 18, ""), IF(ROW()=2, 18+COLUMN()-MATCH(18, $1:$1, 0), ""))

Row 1: | 10 | 12 | 18 | 25 | 30 |
Row 2: |    |    | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |\

I get the 18in Row 2 in the right place, but the remains numbers 19..... do not populate
(I got this formula of an AI engine)

Which excel version are you using? Are you getting any errors or just 18 in row 2 below the 18 in row 1? Where on your sheet is your row 1?

=HSTACK(EXPAND("",1,MATCH(18,A1:E1,0)-1,""),SEQUENCE(1,9,18,1))

Does it for me, but I think you need Excel 365. Unclear if that's an issue.
SEQUENCE(1,9,18,1)

Change this bit if you like other numbers:
1 is the amount of rows you want (so in this case, keep it to 1);
9 is the amount of columns (or values) you want;
18 is the start value;
1 is the increase in value starting from 18.

I made it dynamic:
=LET(n,18,
     L,8,
     m,XMATCH(n,1:1),
     s,SEQUENCE(,L+m,1+n-m),
IF(s<n,"",s))

n being the number you want to match.
L being the size of the sequence from the match to the end.
You can change these if required.
